# Where can I find the phpsessid of a page (it's neither in the cookies nor the url)?

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, cookies

I am currently trying to automate some actions on a website only using http requests.
I'm using nodejs for the bot and so far I had no problems with cookies, csrftoken etc. But for one request, the browser sends a phpsessid within the cookies

```
cookieStringA   7163240,7166759
dev_ref_no  vfmTVB
login_token cfd3deexxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx3eec62
PHPSESSID   e2xxxxxxxxxxxxotv1
sec_advice  sec_advice
X-Access-Token  e84fxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxa001
X-Client-Id wg_desktop_website
X-Dev-Ref-No    vfmTVB
X-Refresh-Token 495xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxaa85
```

copied from firefox.
I googled around and read everywhere, that the phpsessid is normally stored in the cookies, but it's neither the request cookie jar (all other cookies are there) nor can I find it in the browser when using document.cookie.
But on the same page, when I click the send button, the request has this phpsessid.

The website I'm using this on is www.wg-gesucht.de
Do you guys have any hint on where I can find this phpsessid?

Thanks in advance,
T0Bi

Comment: Going to that page the only cookie being set is one named `PHPSESSID` as expected.

Comment: No cookies for me.. https://i.imgur.com/aFBvGwy.png @Dave

Comment: Both FF and Chrome got a cookie BUT, it is a http only cookie which may be related to the problem you're having. It looks like the site forces httpS. Here is the [Chrome cookie](http://dynacompsolutions.com/images/Chrome_cookie.png) I get and thet [Firefox cookie](http://dynacompsolutions.com/images/FF_Cookie.png) I get.

Comment: Oh ok, so if I understand this correctly, this http only cookie can't be accessed through javascript?  
If this is the case, is there another possibility to get the value of phpsessid other than using chrome/firefox dev tools or do I have to get the value from my browser before starting the bot?

Comment: Update: Found the way myself..  
The phpsessid can be found in the response header when first visiting the site, and this works for my program as well.   
Thanks @Dave for the help

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. I (incorrectly) assumed that you were looking at the response from the first visit to the site as that is where things like the PHP session ID variable are usually delivered.